# how to connect instagram API to view specific account use python to get fast real time

Tags: dataframe, dataset, data-science, instagram, exploratory-data-analysis

I want to do research on certain Instagram accounts to get the information I want quickly and always get the latest data. how to connect instagram API to view specific account to get fast real time dataset in python

Comment: will [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61010431/how-to-start-with-the-instagramapi-in-python) help you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start with the InstagramAPI in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61010431/how-to-start-with-the-instagramapi-in-python)